# How to install/default to the command line version of Emacs?

Tags: linux, command-line, apt, emacs

I installed Emacs using `sudo apt-get install emacs`. The problem is that when I launch Emacs from the command line (e.g. `emacs main.c`) it opens Emacs with a GUI. I prefer the command line version which runs in the terminal emulator.

How can I install (or change some default) so that Emacs will open in the command line instead of a GUI?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Installing `emacs-nox` instead of `emacs` should do the trick.

Comment: In Debian/Ubuntu, the "no X" flavor of Emacs has a version number embedded: so the package name is `emacs23-nox`.

Comment: ^This (what riccardo said)

Answer (score 20):

If you would like to start Emacs in the terminal and without any X11 graphics support, just call it with the `-nw` command line switch:

```
emacs -nw #...other options
```

You can set up a shell alias if you're doing this frequently.

This works also in the cases where you don't have control over what is installed.

Comment: Additionally, if the $DISPLAY environment variable is not set, emacs will use the terminal version.

Answer (score 1):

Starting emacs with `emacs -nw` should do the trick.